# Tailwind doesn't recognise all w-* styles

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

My tailwind.config.js file looks like

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  content: ['./pages/**/*.tsx', './core/**/*.tsx', './components/**/*.tsx'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variant: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```

**post.css**

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

If the `w-4` utility-class is applied to a div

```html
<div className="w-4">...</div>
```

I can find the definition in the `global.css` file. If I change to any other value (e.g. `w-8`), there is no effect - `w-8` doesn't appear in `global.css`.

The application is a TS / Next.js application.

VC code shows me a tooltip:

```css
.w-8 {
    width: 2rem/* 32px */;
}
```

**package.json**

```json
    "next-fonts": "^1.5.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.6",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
```

Still have styled-components in the app - migrating to TWCss.

Comment: Are you building the new CSS every change?

Comment: I'm using default hot-reload provided by next.js and running app in dev mode. Hope I don't need to build the app for each change.

Comment: Even a clean build didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Suppose this might be the issue - https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/9667

Comment: also check that tailwind.config.js "content" section will hit the file you're writing. If you're writing a .html file for example, a rule like "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}" won't see your file and won't glean used tailwind classes from it. You'd need to go "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,html}

Comment: All css are contained in *.tsx files. Not sure whether there is some TW cache. After I've removed whole .next folder and invoked `y build` I have seen in .next/static/css/7cd.....e2.css file some weird css definition (like .w-8). There was no reference to w-8 in the whole code base.

Comment: As a temp fix I'm periodically saving unchanged tailwind.config.js file. This somehow triggers update of CSS file

Comment: Both `jit` and `variant` are no longer used by the latest version of Tailwind. You might consider upgrading to 3.0+.

Comment: I've updated the project deps and afterwards haven't had any issue. Ty